# Regarding unit testing best practices

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I have been tasked with testing an existing application, and I've done so with my own in the past, but I am a little unsure of whether I am using the right approach.

Let's say I have the following example:

Class `users` has a function called `getAll()` which returns the list of users by querying the database. There are (as far as I can tell) two straightforward ways to test this functionality:

- Use the same query code that the `getAll()` function uses, independently in the unit test. Then, perform the `getAll()` call and assert the results.
- Have a data provider give the unit test data that is of the format that is expected, hard-coded to values we know are contained in the database. For example, we would pass a hard-coded array containing all users in the format the the `getAll()` function expects, and assert the results.

Although the second approach seems more in line with testing, it has the added results of adding a layer of security risk. Anyone with access to the test suite would also have plaintext access to a lot of potentially sensitive data. On top of that, depending on database size queries like the above could make the tests ridiculously long for very little reason.

Which would be the preferred approach?

Comment: If you need some database to test your code, then of course what you have is an integration test rather than a unit test.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit testing on code that uses the Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391249/unit-testing-on-code-that-uses-the-database)

Comment: @unigeek That's really not helpful at all - though you are technically correct. Stubbing the database would be an enormous effort at this point (it is a relatively mature application), and I do not see the difference between using a stub or a real connection in this instance since the values will have to be identical.

Comment: @user991710 It might be helpful if you did not understand the distinction--I do see you referred to "unit testing" in your question title, so it certainly was not obvious to me that you did. I like to help out in unit testing--finding this one mislabeled cost me time.

Answer (score 0):

In the both approaches you suggest to work with the real DB and compare the results. I think that the proper unit test should be able to verify the function behaviour without connection to the real resource. I would suggest to change the connection string (that may be the function parameter) to some test database with the similar users table and verify the function behaviour. In this way you will not meet any security risk and the unit test (or tests) will be independent.