# Unit tests to test the Web methods of a Web service which does some database transactions using NUnit

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, nunit

How do I write unit tests to test the Web methods of a Web service using NUnit?

The web methods in this application will add,update and delete a record in the database.
The unit test will test a web method whether a record has been inserted in the database, the webmethod calls a method in data access layer to perform this action.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it's appropriate to be testing the end result of your web service with a unit test. Also, what you are trying to do is called an "integration test", and not a unit test.

What you can do, however, is to:

- Write unit tests to check if your data access layer (DAL) is working properly
- Write unit tests to see if your web method is properly accessing your DAL

You might also want to look at a question I raised before: [How do I unit test persistence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046/how-do-i-unit-test-persistence) to provide you more insight.

If you really are adamant to be able to do this however, it is possible to create such unit tests using [MbUnit](http://mbunit.com), which has the `Rollback` attribute.

```
[Rollback]
public void Test_database_persistence()
{
    //any database access you perform here will be put inside a transaction 
    //and rolled back afterwards
}
```

MbUnit is totally compatible with NUnit, so you could still use tests you've already written with NUnit.