# Should you test your DAO as well as your dumb layer model?

Tags: java, junit, dao

Sorry, I can see this has been asked a few other times in different ways but I'm still not entirely certain of the answer.

If I have a DAO object and a model layer object, is it good practice to write a unit test for both classes or just implement the model layer through the DAO object test?

Thanks,

David

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I unit test persistence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046/how-do-i-unit-test-persistence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably many opinions on this sort of question, so you are unlikely to get certainty ;-)

'Thin' or 'dumb' objects with no real functionality may not deserve their own tests (only test things that can actually go wrong). So a combined unit test would be OK.

I would add unit tests for the model layer objects if they grow in complexity/functionality, because finer-grained, localised tests will localise any failures better, and are more likely to run fast and therefore be run frequently.

If you have any coarser-grained end-to-end or 'integration' tests, then these will give some coverage of both kinds of object and *may* pick up trivial errors missed by the absence of dedicated unit tests... but it's a calculated risk /  judgement.